# VC++ 2012 skips glew library for some reason

Tags: visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2012, external

I am trying to link glew32.lib in vc++ and I am getting unresolved externals. I set show progress to verbose to see what was happening and I get this output:

> ...
>            Referenced in OpenGL32.lib(OPENGL32.dll)
>            Loaded OpenGL32.lib(OPENGL32.dll)
>        Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\glew32.lib:
>        Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x86\kernel32.lib:
>          Found _*imp*_GetLastError@0
>            Referenced in main.obj
>   ...

So it looks to me like its just skipping the .lib entirely? At the end of the output it tells me that glew32.lib is unused. I'm including the header, and getting no errors other than the unresolved externals. Why is it skipping over linking this file?